# How to attach behaviour to a document

Tags: javascript, dom-events, code-injection, unobtrusive-javascript

I am trying to bind the `KeyDown` event to all "Input type=text" controls in the document.
I can't rely on CSS selectors because the page change dynamically, so I only know that when
there is an "Input type=text" in the page, I must catch the keydown event and do something with it....

I heard about `document.addEventListener()` but I am not sure if this is the good approach and how to use it.

I am newbie with Javascript and DOM, help please.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, I found by myself the answer so I will share it.

my objective is catch all keydown events so I use addEventListener with the 3 parameters you can see below, first: event type name, second:function event handler,third: boolean Required that specifies whether the event needs to be captured or not.

window.onload = function () {

```
if (document.addEventListener)
{

//attach the event listener which acts globally to the document:
document.addEventListener("keydown",justDoIt,true);

}
```

}

function justDoIt(){ alert("hobbes");}

Finally, one more thing is missing, I dont know how to detect the id of the element where the event was triggered....if someone knows please reply.

That's all :P    BTW just tested on Safari.¡ but it would work over IE and FireFox....